# Transferring data from file geodatabase (.gdb) to cassandra?

Tags: file-geodatabase, big-data, data-transfer

I want to store my spatial data in cassandra.

I want to import data from an existing file geodatabase(.gdb) which has a table containing boundaries of polygons and a table containing point data.

I have individully converted all the tables to csv format and ingested them via fat table to cassandra but I am still worried that the route I am taking is a long one.

Is there a workflow or technique that can directly import .gdb tables to cassandra without converting them to csv?

[Storing features in NoSQL database like Cassandra?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28301) does not have anything about inserting data.

Comment: Might be helpful https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28301/storing-features-in-nosql-database-like-cassandra

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: i have added the limited research what i am able to do but this concept of cassandra and other nosql database is pretty new to me, i would appreciate help if possible but on ground of no research please dont hold the question . This concept is really new to most of GIS professionals if you would guide me i can contribute by posting a working solution.